# Request Aggregator / Middle-tier design pattern for costly requests

Tags: java, c#, multithreading, design-patterns, zeromq

I'm working on a program that will have multiple threads requiring information from a web-service that can handle requests such as:
"Give me `[Var1, Var2, Var3]` for `[Object1, Object2, ... Object20]`"

and the resulting reply will give me a, in this case, 20-node XML (one for each object), each node with 3 sub-nodes (one for each var).

My challenge is that each request made of this web-service costs the organization money and, whether it be for 1 var for 1 object or 20 vars for 20 objects, the cost is the same.

So, that being the case, I'm looking for an architecture that will:

1. Create a request on each thread as data is required
2. Have a middle-tier "aggregator" that gets all the requests
3. Once X number of requests have been aggregated (or a time-limit has reached), the middle-tier performs a single request of the web-service
4. Middle-tier receives reply from web-service
5. Middle-tier routes information back to waiting objects

Currently, my thoughts are to use a library such as [NetMQ](http://netmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with my middle-tier as a server and each thread as a poller, but I'm getting stuck on the actual implementation and, before going too far down the rabbit-hole, am hoping there's already a design pattern / library out there that does this substantially more efficiently than I'm conceiving of.

Please understand that I'm a noob, and, so, ANY help / guidance would be really greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!!!

Comment: I understand I'm not posting any code / asking for a particular problem to be solved, and, so, understand why I'm getting down-voted, BUT I'm hoping someone just knows of the correct design pattern to point me towards.... No direct code needed....

Comment: I think the problem might be that some folks still regard your question as too broad; or would expect answers to be opinion-based. Or maybe they don't take the time to read the full question and to grasp that you actually have a "programming" problem for which you are looking for answers.

Comment: Thanks, @Jägermeister - It's tough since it is a real problem, but I don't have specific code to share... I'd post design pattern diagrams if that helped :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Overview

From the architectural point of view, you just sketched out a good approach for the problem:

1. Insert a proxy between the requesting applications and the remote web service
2. In the proxy, put the requests in the request queue, until at least one of the following events occurs

   1. The request queue reaches a given length
   2. The oldest request in the request queue reaches a certain age
3. Group all requests in the request queue in one single request, removing duplicate objects or attributes
4. Send this request to the remote web service
5. Move the requests into the (waiting for) response queue
6. Wait for the response until one of the following occurs

   1. the oldest request in the response queue reaches a certain age (time out)
   2. a response arrives
7. Get the response (if applicable) and map it to the according requests in the response queue
8. Answer all requests in the response queue that have an answer
9. Send a timeout error for all requests older than the timeout limit
10. Remove all answered requests from the response queue

## Technology

You probably won't find an off-the-shelf product or a framework that exactly matches you requirements. But there are several frameworks / architectural patterns that you can use to build a solution.

### C#: RX and LINQ

When you want to use C#, you could use [reactive extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) for getting the timing and the grouping right.

You could then use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) to select the attributes from the requests to build the response and to select the requests in the response queue that either match to a certain part of a response or that timed out.

### Scala/Java: Akka

You could model the solution as an actor system, using several actors:

1. An actor as the gateway for the requests
2. An actor holding the request queue
3. An actor sending the request to the remote web service and getting the response back
4. An actor holding the response queue
5. An actor sending out the responses or the timeouts

An actor system makes it easy to deal with concurrency and to separate the concerns in a testable way.

When using Scala, you could use its "monadic" collection API (`filter`, `map`, `flatMap`) to do basically the same as with LINQ in the C# approach.

The actor approach really shines when you want to test the individual elements. It is very easy [to test each actor individually](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html), without having to mock the whole workflow.

### Erlang/Elixir: Actor System

This is similar to the Akka approach, just with a different (functional!) language. Erlang / Elixir has a lot of support for distributed actor systems, so when you need an ultra stable or scalable solution, you should look into this one.

### NetMQ / ZeroMQ

This is probably too low level and brings in to few infrastructure. When you use an actor system, you could try to bring in NetMQ / ZeroMQ as the transport system.

Comment: Truly, all I needed - Reactive Extensions look like a great addition for this too!! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @JohnBustos then check out that great documentation for reactive extensions http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/00_Foreword.html

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of using a queue looks good to me.

This is one possible solution to your problem and I'm sure there are countless other solutions that can do what you need.

1. Have a "publish queue" (PQ) and a "consume queue" (CQ)
2. Clients subscribe to CQ and MT subscribes to PQ
3. Clients publish the requests to PQ
4. MT Listens to PQ, aggregates requests and dispatches to farm in a thread
5. Once the results are back, this thread separates the results into req/res pair
6. It then publishes the req/res pairs to the CQ
7. Each client picks the correct message and processes it

Long(er) version:

Have your "middle tier" to listen to a queue (to which, the clients publish messages) and aggregate the requests until N number of requests have come through or X amount of time has passed.

One you are ready, offload the aggregated request to a thread to call your farm and get the results. A bigger problem will most likely arise when you need to communicate this back to the clients.

For that, you probably need another queue that all your clients subscribe to and once your result batch is ready (say 20 responses in XML) from the farm, the thread that called the farm will separate the XML results into their corresponding request/response pair and publish to this queue. Each client will need to pick up the correct request/response pair from the queue and process it.

This will not be a webservice in the traditional sense since the wait times can be prohibitively long and you don't want to maintain a connection which is why I suggest the queue.

You can also have your consumer queue to be topic based, meaning you only publish the req/res pairs to the consumer that asked for it and don't broadcast it (so the client doesn't have to "pick the correct req/res". It will be taken care of based on the topic name). Almost all queues support this.

Comment: Thank you so much, Kha!! - A great solution... The only reason I gave the points to Stefan was due to the extra elaboration and the link to reactive extensions, but thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: @JohnBustos That's absolutely fine. We're not here for virtual points :) Hopefully you have enough information about what you need to do and are able to implement it easily.

Comment: Thank you so much for understanding and being "one of the good ones", @kha!! - Truly thanks!!!